# Get Rails application domain name without request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to get Rails` app domain name without use of the request?

I know how to get URL from the request, but what if there is no request and Rails is just running a delayed job task, can i get a domain name of the server where the Rails app is hosted?

Comment: Yes, `default_url_options`.

Comment: that is assuming that option is set. is there a way to get fetch this info in Rails from the webserver?

Comment: I would just define it in an ENV var if you need to access it like that.

Comment: @max do you mean hardcode it in first and then fetch? is there a way to get it without hardcoding it?

Comment: Yes hardcode it. The other alternative is to pass the domain name to the delayed job when it is spooled. `SomeJob.perform_later(domain: request.domain, ...)`. I would probably use an ENV var together with `default_url_options` though as it will let you link to things properly in mailers.

Comment: Are you running one app for multiple domains?

Comment: @Coco, no but developing the app that can be shipped to different clients, who at the moment are not required to put the domain name in the config. Would be ideal if i could get those attributes from the webserver config

Comment: Normally when you deploy app, you will need to set the `host` for `default_url_option`, that's where you can get the host name. I usually put the host in ENV, so we have `HOST='domain-a.com'`, and `default_url_option = { host: ENV['HOST'] }`, and on your worker you can access the host via `ENV['HOST']` as well, make sense?

Comment: @Coco, it does.. but then again it would mean that our clients who would be deploying the app on their domains would need to do this extra step, which they are not required to do at the moment. i'm not sure if i can introduce any more setup steps for our clients unfortunately..

Comment: Does your app send out email? I suppose you have something like this in your config `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://localhost:3000" }`, do you?

Comment: unfortunately i have it as config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => MyApp::Config::Reader.get('smtp_default_url')....

Comment: Well, then I guess you can get the host from the same code as you put there.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a per se way of doing this due to how Rails is built but if it is a big enough project it might me stored somewhere.

So you could look for a place where it is being set and use that elsewhere.

For example, if the project uses [request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) you could search for something like:

`RequestStore.store[:host] = SomeTable.stored_host_name`

And use `SomeTable.stored_host_name` in your worker or migration or the place you want to use it which doesn't have a request at hand.

Have a great day!